# Hibernate @JoinColumn in both entities for 1-m relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose there is a 1-m relationship between Department and Employee which department can have many employees and one employee can be in only one department. I have depId as a foreign key in the Employee table. Below is how Entities looks like with setters and getters,

```
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long empId;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
    private Department dept;

    public Long getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
}



@Entity
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long deptId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
    @IndexColumn(name = "idx")
    private Set<Employee> listEmp;
}
```

Ealier Department has the attribute mappedBy and now both entities have joinColumn both entities are the owner of the relationship right?

My doubt is when i create Department first and then create a set of Employees and set the department i created and save the department object it works fine. But then i just try to Create a department and Create a Employee and set the department there and save the Employee object it gives me below exception.

> Hibernate: insert into Employee (deptId, name) values (?, ?) Exception
>   in thread "main" org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object
>   references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance
>   before flushing: hello.domain.Department

Shouldn't it work both ways?

Answer (score 4):

> Ealier Department has the attribute mappedBy and now both entities have joinColumn both entities are the owner of the relationship right?

Not right. Now, instead of having a OneToMany bidirectional association, you have two distinct unidirectional associations, that Hibernate tries to map using the same column, leading to unpredictable behavior.

You should use the `mappedBy` attribute on the one side.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/:

> 2.2.5.3.1.1. Bidirectional
>
> Since many to one are (almost) always the owner side of a
>   bidirectional relationship in the JPA spec, the one to many
>   association is annotated by @OneToMany(mappedBy=...)

Followed by an example, followed by:

> Troop has a bidirectional one to many relationship with Soldier
>   through the troop property. You don't have to (must not) define any
>   physical mapping in the mappedBy side.
>
> To map a bidirectional one to many, with the one-to-many side as the
>   owning side, you have to remove the mappedBy element and set the many
>   to one @JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to false.

Note that there is always only one 'owning' side.

Comment: thanks but the author of below article did so. thats why i confused. any particular reason which you can see, http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can cascade the add operation , the final result is

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "deptId")
private Department dept;
```