# Hibernate Many to One Relationship with @JoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Recently I encountered a fuzzy question about many-to-one/one-to-many relationship of Hibernate.

Suppose we have a profile, which may have multiple addresses. And the database tables will be like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE PROFILE (
    PROFILE_ID NUMBER, 
    CONSTRAINT PROFILE_PK PRIMARY KEY (PROFILE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ADDRESS (
    ADDRESS_ID NUMBER, 
    PROFILE_ID NUMBER, 
    CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_PK PRIMARY KEY (ADDRESS_ID), 
    CONSTRAINT ADDRESS_FK FOREIGN KEY (PROFILE_ID) REFERENCES PROFILE (PROFILE_ID)
);
```

Based on definitions by Hibernate, when creating entities, address will be the "owning side" entity (using @JoinColumn), while profile will be the "non-owning side" entity (using "mappedBy"):

```
// non-owning side entity
@Entity
public class Profile {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private long profileId;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "profile")
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

// owning side entity
@Entity
public class Address {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private long addressId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private Profile profile;
}
```

However, in real practice of my office project, for the similar scenario, they are marking both "owning side" and "non-owning side" entities with @JoinColumn. And Hibernate is not throwing error:

```
// non-owning side entity
@Entity
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private long profileId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private List<Address> addresses;
}

// owning side entity
@Entity
public class Address {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
    private long addressId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PROFILE_ID")
    private Profile profile;
}
```

How could this happen? And in Hibernate's view, since @JoinColumn will applies to a foreign key only, does that mean "PROFILE_ID" can be both primary key and foreign key?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012494/hibernate-joincolumn-in-both-entities-for-1-m-relationship